# other way to track URL of client in react native expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, expo, google-oauth

I'm trying to create sign-in with google in the browser and to track the URL client for getting the token at the end of the process from the URL,
first I tried to open the google URL using webView and the _onNavigationStateChange for tracking the URL,
but I can"t do it because of this warning:

> error 403:disallowed_useragent
> Google can't sign you in safely inside this app. You can use Google sign in by visiting this app's website in a browser like Safari or Chrome

[warning image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AshZ2.jpg)

Is their other way to track the client URL maybe using Linking or WebBrowser?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

after trying many ways to solve it I used:

```js
<WebView


        source={{ uri: "...." }}
        userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"
        originWhitelist={["https://*", "http://*", "file://*", "sms://*"]}
      />
```

and it's work for me perfectly